# find row or column containing maximum value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How do I find the row or column which contains the array-wide maximum value in a 2d numpy array?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you only need one or the other:

```
np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=1))
```

for the column, and

```
np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=0))
```

for the row.

Comment: this works perfect for integer elements but what for float ?

Comment: `argmax` doesn't return the array-wide maximum index, it only computes it across the axis.

```np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=1))```
computes the the maximums for each row, across the columns. Not array wide.

Answer (score 26):

You can use `np.argmax` along with `np.unravel_index` as in

```
x = np.random.random((5,5))
print np.unravel_index(np.argmax(x), x.shape)
```

Comment: This is the most efficient solution here proposed.

Comment: `np.argmax(np.max(x, axis=1))` is not comparable with this way in terms of performance; It is the fastest.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `np.where(x == np.max(x))`.

For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,3,1]])
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 1]])
>>> np.where(x == np.max(x))
(array([1]), array([2]))
```

The first value is the row number, the second number is the column number.

Comment: this can return more than 1 value if there is a tie

Answer (score 4):

`np.argmax` just returns the index of the (first) largest element in the flattened array. So if you know the shape of your array (which you do), you can easily find the row / column indices:

```
A = np.array([5, 6, 1], [2, 0, 8], [4, 9, 3])
am = A.argmax()
c_idx = am % A.shape[1]
r_idx = am // A.shape[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.argmax()` directly.

The example is copied from [the official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

```
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) + 10
>>> a
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
>>> np.argmax(a)
5
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=0)
array([1, 1, 1])
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1)
array([2, 2])
```

`axis = 0` is to find the max in each column while `axis = 1` is to find the max in each row. The returns is the column/row indices.