# How do I get the array with maximum value from an array of arrays only considering one specific elememnt per array

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
[[0, 46.0], [1, 83.0], [2, 111.0], [3, 18.0], [4, 37.0], [5, 55.0], [6, 0.0], [7, 9.0], [8, 9.0]]
```

I want to return the array where the second element is the highest. In this example: [2, 111]

How can I do that?

Until now I have tried numpy.amax(array, axis=0) and numpy.amax(array, axis=1). But they do not consider my condition, that I just want to consider the last element per array.

Comment: `max(my_list, key=lambda x: x[1])` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find row or column containing maximum value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332205/find-row-or-column-containing-maximum-value-in-numpy-array)

Comment: @Asocia your solution works fine for me. In the answer section s.o. gave the same answer. As your answer came sooner I would recognize your answer as solution if you would post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `max` with a `key` argument:

```
result = max(arr, key = lambda x : x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you array is an numpy array, you can use `np.argmax` to get the index and slice:

```
a[np.argmax(a[:,1])]
# array([  2., 111.])
```